# How to get the request initiator script in a Chrome web extension?

Tags: google-chrome, request, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

I'm working a Chrome extension in manifest V3. I would like to see what script is the initiator of a request. In the Chrome developer tools, under the network tab, you can see this in the "initiator" column. However, when I log the initiator in my extension, only the url shows up.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(manageRequestList, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ["requestBody"]);

function manageRequestList(request) {
    console.log(request.initiator);
    // logs: "https://www.google.com"
}
```

Current outcome: https://www.google.com.
Preferred outcome: scriptname.js

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: webRequest's `initiator` is a completely different thing, see the documentation. To find the script you'll need to patch `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` in [page context](/a/9517879) as shown [in this example](/a/48134114), then use `new Error().stack` in your patched code.

Comment: @wOxxOm That sounds like a good solution for my problem, thanks! Could you make it into an official answer with some extra explanation?